# Redict to random site from text array after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var textArray = [
    'www.google.com',
    'www.stackoveflow.com'
  ];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);

  link.setAttribute('src', textArray[randomNumber]);

  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = link;
  }, 1000);
});
```

I need a script which grabs one random link from `textArray` and redirects the user to it after a delay. How can I do that?

Comment: Try using `href` instead of `src`. The `src` attribute is for images/javascript/css tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct, you just have two issues. Firstly, you need to use absolute URLs when redirecting, so add `http://` to the links.

Secondly, `link` needs to be a string so that you can provide it to `window.location`. Therefore it will not have a `setAttribute` function. You can just set it equal to the random value from the `textArray`. Try this:

```js
var textArray = [
  'http://www.google.com',
  'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
link = textArray[randomNumber];

setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.assign(link);
}, 1000);
```